# Canonical English edition of Dellacherie and Meyer's "Probabilities and Potential"

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, potential-theory

*Probabilities and Potential* by Dellacherie and Meyer is a "bible" of probabilistic potential theory, Markov processes, and many related topics.  I want my library to acquire it, but I am a bit confused by the several volumes and editions.

What specific books constitute the "canonical" English edition of this work?

Does all of the original French material currently exist in English translation?

Answer (score 9):

The original French edition of *Probabilities and Potential* contains 24 chapters spread over five volumes, as outlined [here.](http://www.eyrolles.com/Accueil/Auteur/claude-dellacherie-87057%0A) The English translation of chapters 1 through 13 is spread over three volumes in the series "North-Holland Mathematics Studies". Chapters 14 through 24 on Markov processes have not yet been translated into English, as far as I am aware. Since North-Holland was absorbed by Elsevier, that publisher now distributes the English translations. You can browse them on Amazon, [volume A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444558586) (chapters 1-4), [volume B](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444557636) (chapters 5-8), and [volume C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444557075) (chapters 9-13). I would refer to the "North-Holland Mathematics Studies" as the "canonical" edition, in that there are no other English translations (and I presume Elsevier would not allow them).